# Getting NameError: name 'bot_token' is not defined py.test

Tags: python, pytest

I am getting hit with a NameError: name 'bot_token' is not defined when I try to run pytest, even though I am importing the all the necessary files (or clearly maybe not).

Directory structure:

```
bot/
-src/
--__init__.py
--my_bot.py
--bot_token.py
-tests/
--test-sample.py
```

test-sample.py

```
import src.my_bot
import src.bot_token

def test
...
```

my_bot.py

```
import src.bot_token

client.run(bot_token.bot_token)

...
```

bot_token.py

```
bot_token = 'blahblahblah'
```

When I try to run `python3 -m pytest`, I get hit with the following error:

```
_________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_sample.py _________________________________________________
tests/test_sample.py:2: in <module>
    import src.my_bot
src/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from .my_bot import my_bot
src/my_bot.py:278: in <module>
    client.run(bot_token.bot_token)
E   NameError: name 'bot_token' is not defined
======================================================== short test summary info ========================================================
ERROR tests/test_sample.py - NameError: name 'bot_token' is not defined
```

How do I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `src.bot_token` and then referencing `bot_token.bot_token`. That name does not exist. Try using `src.bot_token` or maybe `src.bot_token.bot_token` on line 3.

Comment: I removed the `src.` from `src.bot_token` since the files are in the same directory, and now the error message changed to: 
```src/my_bot.py:5: in <module>
    import bot_token
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bot_token'```

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't expect that to work either. Try what I suggested.

Comment: Oh wow it worked! But now I'm running into the issue of when I run the bot with `python3 src/my_bot.py` I get this:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/my_bot.py", line 5, in <module>
    import src.bot_token
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'```

Comment: Have a look at the tutorials on structuring a python project and integration practices with pytest: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/ https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html